# How do I connect a kubernetes cluster to an external SQL Server database using docker desktop?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, docker, kubernetes

I need to know how to connect my Kubernetes cluster to an external SQL Server  database running in a docker image outside of the Kubernetes cluster.

I currently have two pods in my cluster that are running, each has a different image in it created from asp.net core applications. There is a completely separate (outside of Kubernetes but running locally on my machine localhost,1433) docker image that hosts a SQL Server database. I need the applications in my Kubernetes pods to be able to reach and manipulate that database. I have tried creating a YAML file and configuring different ports but I do not know how to get this working, or how to test that it actually is working after setting it up. I need the exact steps/commands to create a service capable of routing a connection from the images in my cluster to the DB and back.

- Docker SQL Server creation (elevated powershell/docker desktop):

  ```
  docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest

  docker run -d -p 1433:1433 --name sql -v "c:/Temp/DockerShared:/host_mount" -e SA_PASSWORD="aPasswordPassword" -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
  ```
- definitions.yaml

  ```
  #Pods in the cluster
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Pod
  metadata:
    name: pod-1
    labels:
      app: podnet
      type: module
  spec:
    containers:
     - name: container1
       image: username/image1

  ---

  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Pod
  metadata:
    name: pod-2
    labels:
      app: podnet
      type: module
  spec:
    containers:
     - name: container2
       image: username/image2

  ---
  #Service created in an attempt to contact external SQL Server DB
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
   name: ext-sql-service
  spec:
   ports:
   - port: 1433
     targetPort: 1433
  type: ClusterIP
  ---
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Endpoints
  metadata:
   name: ext-sql-service
  subsets:
   - addresses:
       - ip: (Docker IP for DB Instance)
     ports:
       - port: 1433
  ```

Ideally I would like applications in my kubernetes cluster to be able to manipulate the SQL Server I already have set up (running outside of the cluster but locally on my machine).

Comment: Ate you able to connect to the dockered mssql server from sql management studio on local machine? The containers need to be on same network for them to be able to see each other.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes I am able to connect to it in sql server mgmt studio Server name: localhost, 1433. Wouldn't that mean they are on the same network... since the db is a docker image? I need exact instructions to make this work, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

When running from local docker, you connection string is NOT your local machine.
It is the local docker "world", that happens to be running on your machine.

host.docker.internal:1433

The above is docker container talking to your local machine.  Obviously, the port could be different based on how you exposed it.

......

If you're trying to get your running container to talk to sql-server which is ALSO running inside of the docker world, that connection string looks like:

ServerName:

my-mssql-service-deployment-name.$_CUSTOMNAMESPACENAME.svc.cluster.local

Where $_CUSTOMNAMESPACENAME is probably "default", but you may be running a different namespace.

my-mssql-service-deployment-name is the name of YOUR deployment (I have it stubbed here)

Note there is no port number here.

This is documented here:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services

Comment: should I insert the connection string into my asp.net core application and rebuild itas docker image, or put it in the YAML file in place of an IP for the DNS resolution. Please provide exact examples/steps, I am not very skilled with kubernetes yet

Comment: The most common is to overlay an environment variable onto the container.  And with "docker run" pass that environment variable VALUE to the container.  It is a bad practice (practically and security) to build config data into the container.

Comment: If you have a db-Password.......then putting the db-password is insecure.  You need to research "kubernetes secrets".  That is too big a topic for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be in kind of service you put. **ClusterIP** enable you juest to connect among pods inside cluster.
To connect to external service you should just change definition of service kind as **NodePort**.

Try to change service definition:

```
#Service created in an attempt to contact external SQL Server DB
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: ext-sql-service
spec:
 type: NodePort
 ports:
 - port: 1433
   targetPort: 1433
```

and execute command:

```
$ kubectl apply -f your_service_definition_file_name.yaml
```

Remember to run this command in proper namespace, where your deployment is configured.

Bad practice is to overlay an environment variable onto the container. And with "docker run" pass that environment variable **VALUE** to the container.

Of course in context of executing docker command

```
$ docker run -d -p 1433:1433 --name sql -v "c:/Temp/DockerShared:/host_mount" -e SA_PASSWORD="aPasswordPassword" -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
```

Putting the db-password visible is insecure. Use Kubernetes secrets.

More information you can find here: [kubernetes-secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/).